# How do I create a PowerBi model where you can model revenue where the user can enter variable values and result in a calculation?

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-modeling, finance, modeling

PowerBi newbie here so I apologize for any confusing language!

My supervisor asked me to work on our fee structure and create a model where he can change the number of basis points and on what amount. The model should show a revenue forecast that can be manipulated based on user input. How do I create that user input parameter that will show in a calculation?

e.g.

- Francis has 10M in assets
- Francis pays 100 basis points on the first 4M
- Francis pays 20 basis points on 6-8M
- Francis pays 10 basis points on the remainder (8M+)

How do I model Francis has X in assets?

Francis pays Y basis points on the first Z

XYZ should all be variables that the user can manipulate and calculations should be in place to produce the fees

Comment: Can you please share an input and expected output ?

Comment: Using [what-f parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-what-if) should help.